# Substring comparison

Tags: algorithm, text

Given a string s respond quickly to queries `(i, j, k, l)` with:

- `-1` if `s[i..j] < s[k..l]`
- `0` if `s[i..j] = s[k..l]`
- `1` if `s[i..j] > s[k..l]`

Assuming

- `i <= j`
- `k <= l`
- `0 <= i, k < s.length - 1`

In other words, perform a lot of lexicographical substring comparisons.

`s[i..j]` is a `(j - i + 1)`-character substring starting at position `i` (indexing from 0) and ending at position `j` (inclusive).

`s[i..j] < s[i..j+1]`, that is a word's prefix is considered less than the word itself).

Because of the number of queries, which is `O(s.length)`, the queries should be answered quickly, that is either in logarithmic or constant time. I've heard rumours that constant time solution is possible (obviously with some preprocessing).

So far I thought about using a hash function, e.g.

`h[i] = (h[i - 1] + x^i * s[i]) mod m`

where `x > 26` (size of the alphabet) and `m` is prime.

Hash for `s[i..j]` would then be calculated by subtracting `h[i]` from `h[j]` and dividing by `x` to a (yet undetermined) power.

This approach has one significant problem - it doesn't allow me to check the less/greater than condition. I initially thought that `h[i..j] < h[k..l]` should imply `s[i..j] < s[k..l]`. This is invalid because

1. Modulo.
2. Let's consider strings `azzz` and `b`, and let's assume that `m` is big enough so that we don't have to perform the modulo operation. It's obvious that `h['azzz'] > h['b']` but `azzz < b`.

This is homework. I'm not looking for implementations, rather general ideas and issues I should learn more about. A complete solution is of course welcome but not required.

Comment: Some questions: is `s[0..1]` a two-character string, and is it the smallest substring?  is `s[i..j] == s[i..j+1]`?

Comment: @BrentWashburne Yes, `s[0..1]` is a two-character string. No, it isn't the smallest substring. Substrings like `s[k..k]` should also be allowed - I've updated the assumptions.
If `a` is `b`'s prefix, then `a < b`.

Comment: It can be solved with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array O(n logn) preprocessing, O(1) time for each query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are from Poland, so here is great article, with very good aproach for that problem : 
http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~jrad/wpg/drobne_oszustwo.pdf

In fact, you are capable to check which word is greater using hashing. You have to use bin search to find first suffix of these two substrings, on which its have different hashes, and then check next letter. It will indicate greater word. The complexity is `O(logm)` where m is size of shorter substring. You can find hash in `O(1)` (use preprocessing of powers) and then bin search, which is `O(logm)`. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of trivial cases that would allow the queries to return immediately, with no pre-processing required.  This is the divide-and-conquer approach.  Break the problem into sub-problems (using Python language in this case):

```
# compare the first character of the substrings
if s[i] < s[k]:
    return -1
if s[i] > s[k]:
    return 1
# first characters are the same
if i == k:       # same substring?
    if j > l:    # first substring is longer
        return 1
    if j < l:    # second substring is longer
        return -1
    return 0     # identical substring
# worst case: same first character but different substrings
# compare s[(i+1)..j], s[(k+1)..l], maybe with a hash
```

Hopefully this reduced your problem set.  I think there may be a smarter hash function.

Comment: You said yourself, these cases are trivial and, in my opinion, they add nothing to the solution.
As you aren't providing any details about the solution, other than "check the first letter and then do something *smart*", I don't see why this is an answer rather than a comment. In fact, what you wrote looks, suspiciously similarly to the naive implementation of string comparison, character by character, which doesn't meet the complexity requirements.

Comment: Would a suffix tree meet the complexity requirements?